# PHP - How get a middle name in LDAP Search?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a website that return data from Active Directory, but when i search a name for exepl: jenifer silva lopes the search jenifer lopes don't show up.
Only if i type the full name. The search is a live one base on AJAX

```
if (TRUE ===  ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $admin."@".$domain, $password)) {

    $search = $_POST["query"];
    $ldap_base_dn = "base exampl";
    $filtro = "(&(|(displayname=*".$search."*)(mail=*".$search."*)(department=*".$search."*)(telephonenumber=*".$search."*))(&(objectClass=person)(objectCategory=contact))(|(extensionAttribute11=Ativo)(extensionAttribute11=Férias)(extensionAttribute11=Licença Mater.)(extensionAttribute11=Outros)(extensionAttribute11=B)))"; //Filtro ajax + filto dn
    $result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $filtro);
    if (FALSE !== $result){            
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
```

Comment: did you try to print all ldap fields and see is there any middle name?

Comment: middleName            http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm

Comment: Yes, i want to some the inicial name with the last one : odin toryn baron 
i want to search : odin baron and have the return .